# Distinguish between validation exception and Unhandled error in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I had written many stored procedures for my application. Some stored procedures return validation exceptions as per project requirement, while in some cases stored procedure return unhandled fatal errors such as

> "Foreign key reference error", "expects parameter which was not supplied" etc.

Now I need to distinguish between those errors in my C# code. In case of unhandled fatal errors, I need to insert error log in database.

Any suggestion on how to distinguish between these two types.

NOTE : I am returning validation exceptions using RAISERROR statement like

`RAISERROR(@ErrorMsg,16,1)`

**UPDATE 1:**

I guess everyone falsely interprets my actual issue.
I may get either user defined validation exception (returned by RAISERROR stmt) OR fatal error from query execution within SP. I need to distinguish between these two types at my C# code. Both exceptions are caught in

```
catch (SqlException ex)
```

block. After some research, I found that ex.Number is 50000 in case of user defined validation exception and in other cases, it is different.

I am thinking of writing condition on that. If any cleaner approach that this, please suggest.

Comment: try and catch is the way to print your mentioned error.where you can handle your error in catch and can insert in your log.

Comment: You can have multiple catch blocks. You could first capture any SQLException, those would be the errors from your sql execution. Then another catch block after which would then be able to catch any otherwise unhandled exception.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the value of the id for this statement.

This error occurred, because the Id of the foreign key is being excluded or beacuse the id isn't insert on the statement

Comment: What are you trying to say here? Are you saying they should set the msg_id for the error? Seems they are getting the message information.

Comment: Use Try Catch and remove this RAISERROR from the Stored procedures, with this, there is the return of the error message in the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Use Try Catch Block in C# code and remove your RAISERROR(@ErrorMsg,16,1) from stored procedures.

You can get exact error message inside catch block and validate it and write log.